# Inject variable into NSIS installer

Tags: php, linux, nsis

Is it possible to programatically inject values into a NSIS installer, that can be used during installation by NSIS from a Linux server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append data to the end of the installer .exe. See the [NSIS wiki](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ReadCustomerData) for a example...

Comment: how do you append data to the end of the exe file in linux?

Comment: I don't know, it really depends on if you are appending binary or text data I guess. You should ask that sort of question on superuser or one of the other stackexchange sites...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't inject the values into the binary NSIS install package - too many points where it could go wrong.

In my past life I kept a Windows installation up-to-date by running the NSIS compiling steps on my Linux box.  I was able to update the dynamic values (version, customer, etc) into the NSIS script, then it would rebuild the installer.

Comment: unfortunately recompile time is prohibitive in this situation, I'd ideally like to be able to perform this operation as part of a web request, I'm working on a completely different approach to this problem but it will be sub-optimal compared to something like this